# Newton's law of motion for extended objects

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

I read somewhere that **Newton's laws may be used even if the object under consideration is an extended body, provided each part of this body has same acceleration.**
Does that mean that if i have a movable pulley with different masses on two ends going in different directions, I can't treat the entire system as a single object? Why is this so?

Answer (score 1):

First of all an extended body is any body other than a point mass. And of course Newton’s laws are not limited to point masses.

As far as your example is concerned, you can consider it as a single object in which case you would be applying Newton’s laws to the center of mass of the system.

Hope this helps

Comment: The center of mass would keep changing as objects around the pulley are free to move, right?

Comment: That depends. Say you had two equal masses moving at constant velocity. Then the center of mass would not change. If you have unequal masses accelerating the acceleration of the center of mass is the weighted average of the two.

Comment: Is it really an "of course"? In Taylor's Classical Mechanics, he seems to say that Newton's laws apply to point masses/particles only, and that we can *derive* corresponding statements for extended bodies?

Comment: @EE18 when I said of course, I meant if the extended body were an ideal rigid body

Comment: Gotcha, but I suppose I am wondering whether we can say that these are axioms, or whether the axioms are for point masses (particles) and that the conclusions for ideal rigid bodies are derived theorems? Of course, this is somewhat a matter of taste, but I'm more so wondering about convention. Is it convention to say that Newton's laws apply only to point particles axiomatically?

Comment: @EE18 can’t say whether it’s axiomatic or not, but as I understand it in quantum mechanics an ideal rigid body is considered a system of particles whose separation distances are fixed.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for your time and the discussion!

Answer (score 1):

The statement should read more precisely that Newton's second law of motion describes the motion of either

1. The motion of a point mass with no dimensions. The forces acting on the point mass affect its motion $$ \vec{F} = m \,\vec{a} $$
2. The motion of the center of mass of a physical rigid body. The forces acting on the body (or the extended body) *only* affects the motion of the center of mass $$ \vec{F} = m \,\vec{a}_{\rm com}$$

This does not mean that every part of the extended body also accelerates with the same amount. Quite the contrary, the acceleration of a moving body is quite complex. But that the forces only describe the motion of a single point on the body.

Answer (score 0):

Newton's laws of motion are a good (but not the only) tool to study the motion of objects. The important questions that we are generally concerned with is to find the equation of motion of the objects so that we have adequate information that helps us predict its future.

It is definitely useful to study the motion of extended objects, in fact, the motion of planets (of course with knowledge of gravitation and a few conservation laws) was very well studied using Newton's laws of motion. But you see, when we study the motion of planets, we don't care whether I am jumping on this planet or how fast is a train moving etc. In fact, we also ignore its rotation when it comes to predicting its future trajectory.

Now, in the case of the pulley system, I am assuming that you might be interested in the motion of the masses attached to both sides of the ropes. Hence, you would not want to consider it as a single object. Suppose, you are throwing the entire pulley system along with the masses attached to it from a 10 storey building to the ground and you are just interested in by what time will it reach the ground, then you may consider it as a single object, but if you are interested how will the parts move in the air while descending. Will the masses entangle the ropes further or will the rope get detached from the pulley etc, then you can't consider it as a single object as every part is going to move differently with respect to the coordinate system fixed at the centre of mass of it.

So, the trick is to know whose motion do you want to study or predict. What can you ignore and what you can't.